# How to pass data to DataSource from a ViewModel when it is initially loaded

Tags: android, android-paging-library

I am using Paging library to get data from a webservice and display it in a recyclerview. However, I am not able to figure out a way to load initial data when the DataSource is loaded initially
I am doing something similar to [this tutorial](https://harunwangereka.medium.com/android-paging-library-with-kotlin-coroutines-b96602e3fae3).

```
override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<String>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<String, RedditPost>) {}
```

I want to pass User.name, User.age etc to be passed from the ViewModel. How do you call this function?

Comment: You can use LiveData.  Subscribe the livedata in your fragment/activity. Post the data to livedata when you get the results.

Comment: @AmitKumar I can get data back that way, my problem is sending data to start the process. The backend end point has a couple of required parameters I need to pass initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't that specific about what you're trying to pass in, so I'll try to cover both scenarios briefly:

1. You have some dynamic argument you need to pass based on UI context (e.g., linking to the middle of a thread):

The [PagedList.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList.Builder#setInitialKey(kotlin.Any)) or any of its variants (LiveData, Rx, etc.), have an `initialKey` argument you can pass in on instantiation, which is passed to `DataSource` as the key in `LoadParams`. This needs to match the `Key` type of your `DataSource` (`Int` for `PositionalDataSource`, etc).

2. You have some dependencies which aren't dynamic based on UI context.

You want to pass any dependencies via your `DataSource`'s constructor, passing it through [DataSource.Factory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/DataSource.Factory) during `.create()`.

Edit: Generally if you trying to send events from the UI upstream and react on this, you'll want to do a `.switchMap`. You didn't mention what architecture or post any code, but assuming you are using `LiveData`, it may look something like:

ViewModel.kt

```
val queryFlow = MutableLiveData<String>("initialQuery")
val pagingDataFlow = queryFlow
  .switchMap { query ->
     LivePagedListBuilder(
       dataSourceFactory = MyDataSourceFactory(query),
       config = ...
     )
       ...
       .build()
  }
  .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

This allows you to start / cancel a new stream on each new query and pass the query into your `DataSource.Factory`.

Comment: I am trying to pass a query string several times but I couldn't find a tutorial that illustrates how to accomplish that. Do I have to invalidate the datasource and create a new one each time the user passes a whole new search query? PagedListBuilder doesn't allow sending dynamic query several times. I am able to send a query from a viewmodel at the beginning and observe the livedata. I would like to pass query whenever the user feels like it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a small sample... it's a bit hard to give you something you can copy without seeing your code, but hopefully you are using `LiveData`. Similar operations also exist in Rx and Flow.